# Script to Sort Sheets by Name in Google Sheets Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use a Google Sheets spreadsheet to manage the files that I am working on. I have roughly 60-70 files at any given time, each of which has a unique file number. Each file is represented in my spreadsheet by a unique sheet named by its file number. File numbers fit the following format: [#]-[##]-[####] (e.g. 5-18-0040). I also have a sheet named "Files" which is a list of all of those sheets and a few other hidden sheets with operations contained in them.

I have cobbled together a script that I had thought would sort those sheets by increasing file number (e.g. 1-15-0023, 2-16-1924, 3-14-2012, 5-17-0040) and then pushes the Files sheet and those hidden sheets to the start. However, it doesn't work. It definitely moves sheets around somewhat, but I still end up with sheets out of order.

Can anyone take a look at this code and tell me what could be failing? For instance, do I need to specify the names as integers (and if so, how?) or is there something else that could be preventing this script from working?

```
function sortSheets () {
  var sheetNameArray = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());
  }
  sheetNameArray.sort(); 
  for( var j = 0; j < sheets.length; j++ ) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[j]));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(j + 1);
  }
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Files"));
  ss.moveActiveSheet(1);
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Court Information"));
  ss.moveActiveSheet(2);
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Timelines"));
  ss.moveActiveSheet(3);
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Template"));
  ss.moveActiveSheet(4);
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Operators"));
  ss.moveActiveSheet(5);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the sorted `sheetNameArray` and verified that it has the order you want? `console.log(sheetNameArray);` will send it to Stackdriver, where you can more easily interact with multiple logs.

Comment: So, upon adding the console.log(sheetNameArray); it decided to work correctly. It also decided that it needed a reload after running the script (understandable), but it worked.
Think I need the logging to make it work? Maybe that slows the script down enough to actually function?

Comment: No idea. Note that you can write your last set a lot more succinctly: `["Files", "Court Information" "Timelines", "Template", "Sheet Operators"].forEach(function (name, index) { ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(name)); ss.moveActiveSheet(1 + index); });`

Comment: Forever learning. I'm a JS hack so much of what I develop is google-fu'ed together. I appreciate the tip and have restructured it. Thanks! Getting an error though on save: "Missing ] after element list." Is there something there that needs to be redone?

Comment: Yeah, I missed a comma after `"Court Information"`. There's a reason code doesn't belong in comments ;)

Comment: That's interesting that adding the console.log worked. I had a similar script before that would rearrange sheet,the script ran and did actually rearrange the sheets but to visually see it you had to refresh the spreadsheet once or twice for the change to take effect. I put it down to a caching issue! I must get that one out again and try it out.

Comment: Yep. Strange issue. It just didn't seem to work on my end. Maybe the console.log will help me debug if it's not doing it properly. 

@tehhowch: Thanks. I looked at that code as well and missed the comma. Always happy to learn.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is suitable for your situation, how about using Sheets API? In my environment, I confirmed that the sheets could be rearranged without reloading spreadsheet. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#SheetProperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, this code actually does work. Thanks to @tehhowch for his or her help as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
function sortSheets () {
  var sheetNameArray = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 

  if (sheets.length <= 2){
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 3; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());
  }

  sheetNameArray.sort(); 

  for( var j = 0; j < sheetNameArray.length; j++ ) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameArray[j]));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(j + 4);
  }
}
```

for my problem, i want the first 3 to stay and any sheet after to sort accordingly. This is a neater way of doing

Comment: I think You should replace   `var sheetNameArray = [];  var sheets = ss.getSheets();` by `var sheetNameArray = [];  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  var sheets = ss.getSheets();`